# How come this conversion from recursion to iteration magically works?

Tags: c#, recursion

Not without trouble, I've been able to convert the following snippet from recursion to iteration.

(thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration) btw)

Recursion:

```
private static Bin Find(Bin bin, int w, int h)
{
    if (bin.Used)
        return Find(bin.Right, w, h) ?? Find(bin.Down, w, h);

    if (w <= bin.W && h <= bin.H)
        return bin;

    return null;
}
```

Iteration:

```
private static Bin Find(Bin bin, int w, int h)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Bin>(new[] {bin});

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var pop = stack.Pop();

        if (pop.Used)
        {
            stack.Push(pop.Down);
            stack.Push(pop.Right);

            continue;
        }

        if (w <= pop.W && h <= pop.H)
            return pop;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now there is something I don't understand, how come it magically works ?

Because when you look out at original implementation:

- while bin is used, keep trying on `Right` bin
- else keep trying on `Down` bin

While on iteration I push both leaves, `Right` and `Down` are popped/processed sequentially but it still works.

**Question:**

Is my code not totally correct but because of the way that data structure is it works anyway ?

Or does my conversion to iteration really match the original recursion?

**Reference:**

Here's the complete algorithm in case you want to look at it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace ABCD
{
    public static class BinPacker
    {
        public static void Fit([NotNull] Size[] sizes)
        {
            if (sizes == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sizes));

            var root = new Bin
            {
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
                W = sizes.Length > 0 ? sizes[0].W : 0,
                H = sizes.Length > 0 ? sizes[0].H : 0
            };

            var rects = new Rect[sizes.Length];

            for (var i = 0; i < sizes.Length; i++)
            {
                var s = sizes[i];
                var w = s.W;
                var h = s.H;
                var n = Find(root, w, h);
                n = n != null ? Split(n, w, h) : Grow(ref root, w, h);

                rects[i] = new Rect(n.X, n.Y, w, h);
            }
        }

        private static Bin Find(Bin bin, int w, int h)
        {
            if (bin.Used)
                return Find(bin.Right, w, h) ?? Find(bin.Down, w, h);

            if (w <= bin.W && h <= bin.H)
                return bin;

            return null;
        }

        private static Bin Split(Bin bin, int w, int h)
        {
            bin.Used = true;

            bin.Down = new Bin
            {
                X = bin.X,
                Y = bin.Y + h,
                W = bin.W,
                H = bin.H - h
            };

            bin.Right = new Bin
            {
                X = bin.X + w,
                Y = bin.Y,
                W = bin.W - w,
                H = h
            };

            return bin;
        }

        private static Bin Grow([NotNull] ref Bin bin, int w, int h)
        {
            if (bin == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bin));

            var canGrowR = h <= bin.H;
            var canGrowD = w <= bin.W;
            var letGrowR = canGrowR && bin.H >= bin.W + w;
            var letGrowD = canGrowD && bin.W >= bin.H + h;

            if (letGrowR)
                return GrowRight(ref bin, w, h);

            if (letGrowD)
                return GrowDown(ref bin, w, h);

            if (canGrowR)
                return GrowRight(ref bin, w, h);

            if (canGrowD)
                return GrowDown(ref bin, w, h);

            return null;
        }

        private static Bin GrowDown([NotNull] ref Bin bin, int w, int h)
        {
            if (bin == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bin));

            bin = new Bin
            {
                X    = 0,
                Y    = 0,
                W    = bin.W,
                H    = bin.H + h,
                Used = true,
                Down = new Bin
                {
                    X = 0,
                    Y = bin.H,
                    W = bin.W,
                    H = h
                },
                Right = bin
            };

            var find = Find(bin, w, h);

            return Split(find, w, h);
        }

        private static Bin GrowRight([NotNull] ref Bin root, int w, int h)
        {
            if (root == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(root));

            root = new Bin
            {
                X    = 0,
                Y    = 0,
                W    = root.W + w,
                H    = root.H,
                Used = true,
                Down = root,
                Right = new Bin
                {
                    X = root.W,
                    Y = 0,
                    W = w,
                    H = root.H
                }
            };

            var node = Find(root, w, h);

            return Split(node, w, h);
        }
    }

    internal sealed class Bin
    {
        public int X { get; set; }

        public int Y { get; set; }

        public int W { get; set; }

        public int H { get; set; }

        public bool Used { get; set; }

        public Bin Down { get; set; }

        public Bin Right { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(X)}: {X}, {nameof(Y)}: {Y}, {nameof(W)}: {W}, {nameof(H)}: {H}, {nameof(Used)}: {Used}";
        }
    }

    [PublicAPI]
    public struct Size : IEquatable<Size>
    {
        public readonly int W, H;

        public Size(int w, int h)
        {
            W = w;
            H = h;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(W)}: {W}, {nameof(H)}: {H}";
        }

        public bool Equals(Size other)
        {
            return W == other.W && H == other.H;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Size other && Equals(other);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (W * 397) ^ H;
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Size left, Size right)
        {
            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Size left, Size right)
        {
            return !left.Equals(right);
        }
    }

    [PublicAPI]
    public struct Rect : IEquatable<Rect>
    {
        public readonly int X, Y, W, H;

        public Rect(int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            W = w;
            H = h;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(X)}: {X}, {nameof(Y)}: {Y}, {nameof(W)}: {W}, {nameof(H)}: {H}";
        }

        public bool Equals(Rect other)
        {
            return X == other.X && Y == other.Y && W == other.W && H == other.H;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Rect other && Equals(other);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = X;
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Y;
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ W;
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ H;

                return hashCode;
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Rect left, Rect right)
        {
            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Rect left, Rect right)
        {
            return !left.Equals(right);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic is based on the fact that stack is the data sturcture which implements FILO (First In, Last Out).

Let's look at the recursion. After you look at `bin`, you move your eye to `bin.Right` and `bin.Down`. The thing is, you can't move your eye to `bin.Down` until you finish your work with `bin.Right`.

From this fact, let's move on to the stack-way.

First, push the first bin.

```
bin - bottom
```

After we look at the popped `bin`, we push `bin.Down` and `bin.Right`. Note that `bin.Down` is pushed first.

```
bin.Right - bin.Down - bottom
```

And again we do the same thing with the popped `bin.Right`.

```
bin.Right.Right - bin.Right.Down - bin.Down - bottom
```

And We figure out that there is nothing to do with `bin.Right.Right`, so pop again to look at `bin.Right.Down`... and the same thing goes on.

Down here, you may have figured out. Until you finish the work with `bin.Right`, `bin.Down` has never popped. That's the magic.